# Alternative to ArcGIS Desktop for software development?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, arcgis-platform

I'm looking for a free and reasonably licensed alternative to ArcGIS Desktop (or maybe just ArcGIS Server).  I'm quite new to GIS, so I'll state some of the things I want to be able to do and you can tell me what alternatives are out there.

I need to be able to convert from GML or Shapefile format to some GIS database format, (I bet I can't do this with GDAL/OGR but I'm not sure).  And then I want to be able to programmatically query the database for assets of certain types within specified bounds.  For instance, I would like to find all roads within a lat/long box and extract their names and their polyline representations.

At this point I am only interested in a programmatic API.  I'm not interested in anything with a GUI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) can convert GML and/or shapefile to [PostGIS](http://www.refractions.net/products/postgis/), [SpatiaLite](https://web.archive.org/web/20201207113240/http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/) and a [number of other datastores](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html), and has a [well developed API](https://gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html). Both postgis and spatialite can support the kind of query you want, though I personally have not done so (actually depending on the details of your queries, you may be able to do all of it in OGR).

Answer (score 5):

Based on your description, you will need the OGR library (to convert from GML/shape to your database) and a spatially enabled database (I would recommend PostGIS).

If you are happy with a raw database to query with SQL, that's all you need. There are plenty of postgres utility libraries, and one for your programming language of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Free GIS Alternatives:

http://www.qgis.org/

http://udig.refractions.net/

http://www.openjump.org/

http://grass.itc.it/

Web GIS

http://mapserver.org/

http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome

*Some require plugins or additional steps to incorporate your GIS requirements

Mapperz uses all of the above with Postgres (with Postgis) as the Spatial Database.

Comment: the first three don't answer the question, "I'm not interested in anything with a GUI".

Comment: whups, sorry, I didn't notice the "no gui" requirement was added after your post. :)

Comment: qgis can be compiled to your own spec with or WITHOUT a GUI if you so choose
https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/branches/1.4/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/gml/will convert your gml 
udig has a SDK again you can build your own from it
http://udig.refractions.net/confluence/display/DEV/1+SDK+Quickstart
OpenJump has too
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jump-pilot/index.php?title=Working_with_GML
hope it helps point you in the right direction.